# What's the difference between `command > output` and `command 2>&1 > output`?

Tags: shell, operating-system

I'm somewhat familiar with the common way of redirecting stdout to a file, and then redirecting stderr to stdout.
If I run a command such as `ls > output.txt 2>&1`, my guess is that under the hood, the shell is executing something like the following c code:

```
close(1)
open("output.txt") // assigned to fd 1
close(2)
dup2(1, 2)
```

Since fd 1 has already been replaced with output.txt, anything printed to stderr will be redirected to output.txt.
But, if I run `ls 2>&1 > output.txt`, I'm guessing that this is instead what happens:

```
close(2)
dup2(1, 2)
close(1)
open("output.txt")
```

But, since the shell prints out both stdout and stderr by default, is there any difference between `ls 2>&1 output.txt` and `ls > output.txt`? In both cases, stdout will be redirected to output.txt, while stderr will be printed to the console.

Comment: Your terminal prints out stdout and stderr by default. They are still separate streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ls >output.txt`, the `stderr` from `ls` goes to the `stderr` inherited from the calling process.  In contrast, with `ls 2>&1 >output.txt`, the `stderr` of `ls` is sent to the `stdout` of the calling process.

Let's try this with an example script that prints a line of output to each of `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
$ cat pr.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "to stdout"
echo "to stderr" 1>&2

$ sh pr.sh >/dev/null
to stderr

$ sh pr.sh 2>/dev/null
to stdout
```

Now if we insert "2>&1" into the first command line, nothing appears different:

```
$ sh pr.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null
to stderr
```

But now let's run both of those inside a context where the inherited `stdout` is going someplace other than the console:

```
$ (sh pr.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null) >/dev/null

$ (sh pr.sh      >/dev/null) >/dev/null
to stderr
```

The second command still prints because the inherited `stderr` is still going to the console.  But the first prints nothing because the "2>&1" redirects the inner `stderr` to the outer `stdout`, which is going to `/dev/null`.

Although I've never used this construction, conceivably it could be useful in a situation where (in a script, most likely) you want to run a program, send its `stdout` to a file, but forward its `stderr` on to the caller as if it were "normal" output, perhaps because that program is being run along with some other programs and you want the first program's "error" output to be part of the same stream as the other programs' "normal" output.  (Perhaps both programs are compilers, and you want to capture all the error messages, but they disagree about which stream errors are sent to.)